# Passing an html elemement itself to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the click of an element I want to passit itself to a javascript function, for various manipulations or to use them in a modal or anything else. My problem is I dont know how to pass an element itself to "this" in a javascript function.

This snippet is giving error, but I dont know right way to pass element itself to the function. Pl help!

```html
<p width="200px" onclick="pick(this)">Hello</p>

<script> 
function pick(this){
console.log(this.width);

}
</script>
```

Comment: pass width instead of this

Comment: `this` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as parameter name. Name it `element` or similar.

Comment: In you function definition try replacing `this` with some other name as this as a keyword in JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a reserved word. Use something like `self`

```html
<p width="200px" onclick="pick(this)">Hello</p>

<script> 
function pick(self){
console.log(self);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to console now width of this element then self.width is not working. How to do it?

Comment: `$(self).width()`

Comment: $--means using jquery?

Comment: Indeed. I used that cause you had the question tagged as `jquery` 

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to achieve using core Javascript

Hello

```
<script> 
function pick(self){
console.log(self.currentTarget.clientWidth);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Use the following code to achieve using core Javascript

<p width="200px" onclick="pick(event)">Hello</p>